# Parameters expected by a JavaScript method

Tags: javascript, methods

I was wondering if it is possible to get the parameter type or the number of parameters expected by a method in Javascript itself?

Something like,
getElementById.length or getElementById.arguments

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your use case? I can't really think up a scenario where you'd need the number of args a function requires during runtime.

Comment: @Michd: [Reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) can be a huge benefit…

Comment: Bergi, I did try them since the output was 0 for the length argument I assumed I was doing something wrong.

Comment: @MichD, it's one of the only ways I can think of to get around the horrendous bug in JavaScript where one can call a ******* function with the wrong number of arguments and the VM will happily and silently continue on in error without ever letting anyone know.  Either that or download a bulky, slow static linter that is as much garbage as JS itself, and all the ones I've seen don't even have this option. (I have to put the following at the top of every damn function: `if (arguments.length != arguments.callee.length) throw fart;`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> get the parameter type

Definitely not possible. JavaScript is weakly typed. You will need to take a look at the documentation to see what parameters a function expects.

> get the number of parameters expected by a method

Yes. You can use the [`length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) of function objects. It contains the number of formal defined parameters, but notice that the functions are still [variadic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) and may accept more or less parameters then their `length` suggests.

> ```
> document.getElementById.length;
> ```

yields `0` for example (at least in Opera, that may differ between implementations).

> `getElementById.arguments`

The [`arguments` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments) of function objects is **deprecated**, and it would have contained the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) during an invocation - not information about the function in general.

Answer (score 0):

*"get the parameter type expected by a function"*

we cannot get the expected parameter type of a particular `function`, because `variables` in `javascript` can change their nature at any moment.

For Example:

```
function test(msg)
{
//something
}
```

the above function can be called like `test("hai")` ,`test(123)`, `test(true)`.

---

May be you could get the parameter type of any function inside of it. like below,

```
test("hello");
function test(msg)
{
alert(typeof msg); //string
}
```